# Insert or update in SQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question with a insert in database:

For example I have the table:

```
id  eur_sell  eur_buy    date
--  --------  -------    ----- 
1   3,4       3,6        2014-02-04
```

How to create a query and verify if today's date was insert make update 
But tomorrow if there now insert make it after that if you do another insert make update

Comment: I need only the how to verify the date

Comment: first you get today date then get date from database and match them if today date is already inserted then update data else insert data . further it will be clear to see your code.

Comment: Whatever you do, first you should get rid of those comma separated values. Read about normalization.

Comment: @fancyPants - I suspect they're not comma separated values, but floats. Some countries use a comma instead of a perdiod as the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

You can using "replace into" this method to insert or update the your record.

If the record is new, it’s insert just as with INSERT. If it’s a duplicate, the new record will replaces the old one

You can refer from here:

http://chevronscode.com/index.php/mysql-check-for-duplicates-before-inserting.html

Answer (score 0):

you have to perform ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Eg.

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,date) VALUES (1,2,date)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = new a;
```

Comment: The key is autoincrement